# How to document an R generic defined in an IF statement

Tags: r, generics, roxygen2

I have an R generic that's set in an IF statement:

```
if (is.null(getGeneric("isIdCurrent"))) {
  setGeneric("isIdCurrent", function(dbObj, ...) standardGeneric("isIdCurrent"))
}
```

If I don't document it, RStudio "Check" will complain about "Undocumented code objects". But if I try to document it (roxygen2 v7.1.1), e.g, like:

```
if (is.null(getGeneric("foo"))) {
#' @rdname myGnrc
  setGeneric("foo", function(dbObj, ...) standardGeneric("foo"))
}
```

RStudio "Clean and Rebuild" will complain about "@rdname Missing name".

If I remove the IF statement, then, of course, all my problems are solved:

```
#' @rdname myGnrc
setGeneric("foo", function(dbObj, ...) standardGeneric("foo"))
```

But I'm trying to maintain someone else code and I'm not sure if it's safe to remove the IF statement.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After some reading and experimenting, I think it's safe to remove the IF statement.